# Access locked Ubuntu Touch mobile

Tags: ubuntu-touch, remote, bq

Today, my BQ Aquaris E5 hit the ground harder than ever before. While the phone seems to be working just fine, display does not react to gestures so I can't type the password to unlock it. I understand that I can't connect the phone while it is locked. I have loved this feature... well... until today. The problem is that local guys told me they don't know how to fix this kind of phone and I will have to send it back to Spain. I REALLY need to access it. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can try connecting a regular mouse (with the USB to microUSB adapter). Then you can try a backup, if needed, before sending it to repair.